# Add Directive using es6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

**my goal: is to add a directive to a component, but the directive isn't loading.**

I'm using [Angular's Best Practices App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub).

I started with [gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) scaffold,

In my previous angular app it was appended to '[app.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)' but this new fragmentation seems to favor injecting the directive via a class. Here's what I've created in my 'header/navbar' component's folder.

**header.directive.js:**

```
'use strict';

class headerNav {

  constructor(){
    this.directive('header-nav', function() {
      return {
        templateUrl: 'header.html'
      };
    });
  }

}

export default headerNav;
```

Comment: Well that code isn't going to work as-is. `directive` isn't defined anywhere there. Maybe you meant to `extend` another class?

Comment: Good thoughts, I'll work on that